# jquery wait for ajax load to complete after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .when

I'm working on a magento site which uses ajax layered navigation.  When the user clicks on a color link in the layered nav it loads a list of the relevent products.  I want to fire a click event after the ajax has completed.

I thought I could use the [jQuery when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function for this but I can't get it working.

```
jQuery( "a#red-hoi-swatch" ).click(function() {
    jQuery.when( jQuery.ajax() ).then(function() {
      jQuery("a[name*='chili-ireye']").click();
    });
});
```

Basically, I want to run `jQuery("a[name*='chili-ireye']").click();` after the ajax has finished when a user clicks the `a#red-hoi-swatch`.

**UPDATE**
I found the ajax responsible for this, it's from the Magento Blacknwhite theme we bought

```
/*DONOT EDIT THIS CODE*/
function sliderAjax(url) {
    if (!active) {
        active = true;
        jQuery(function($) {
            oldUrl = url;
            $('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
            $('#resultLoading').fadeIn(300);
            try {
                $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        callback();
                        if (data.viewpanel) {
                            if ($('.block-layered-nav')) {
                                $('.block-layered-nav').after('<div class="ajax-replace" />').remove();
                                $('.ajax-replace').after(data.viewpanel).remove();
                            }
                        }
                        if (data.productlist) {
                            $('.category-products').after('<div class="ajax-category-replace" />').remove();
                            $('.ajax-category-replace').after(data.productlist).remove();
                        }
                        var hist = url.split('?');
                        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
                            window.history.pushState('GET', data.title, url);
                        }
                        $('body').find('.toolbar select').removeAttr('onchange');
                        $('#resultLoading .bg').height('100%');
                        $('#resultLoading').fadeOut(300);
                        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                        ajaxtoolbar.onReady();
                        jQuery('.block-layered-nav a').off('click.vs');
                        try{
                            ConfigurableSwatchesList.init();
                        }catch(err){}
                    }
                })
            } catch (e) {}
        });
        active = false
    }
    return false
}


function callback(){
    }
```

Comment: why not call the click at the end of the success function in the ajax call?

Comment: Where is the code loading (via ajax) the relevent products when you click on a#red-hoi-swatch ? Is it done elsewhere ? Or do you not put all the code in your example ?

Comment: Provide your ajax so we can see how you are initializing it.

Comment: @EternalHour, just posted it in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the [ajaxComplete() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp):

```
jQuery( "a#red-hoi-swatch" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        jQuery("a[name*='chili-ireye']").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant and works like a charm! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Not done jQuery for a while but do you really need the `.when()`?

Can you not just do

```
jQuery( "a#red-hoi-swatch" ).click(function() {
    var url = 'http://my/api/url';
    jQuery.ajax(url).then(function() {
      jQuery("a[name*='chili-ireye']").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: It didn't work, I'm not sure what to put in the url.  I put in the `href` from the `<a>` which seems to fire the ajax, i.e. `http://dev.mysite.local/clothing.html?hoi_search_colors=109`

Answer (score 1):

You can make any of the following 3

1. calling your click event on the success of your ajax call
2. you can make the asynch property of your ajax call to false;
3. callback the click event on success of your ajax call.

Comment: Setting async property to false is deprecated and in the process of being removed (https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning). It doesn't work on latest Chrome already (2016-04-26).

Answer (score 0):

You can use handlers just after ajax queries or you can define a success callback for the ajax query.
From the jQuery API:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});
```